# Use columns of dataframe as y-values in plotly dash

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

I want to use some (but not all) columns (`['V+', 'V-', 'I_tube', 'I_heat']`) of a dataframe to be plotted against `'time'`. When I hard-code the columns like `y = I_heat` then it works, but I don't know how to make it reactive so that y will change according to the user behaviour.
So far, I got:

```
    from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H4('Dauertest'),
    dcc.Graph(id="graph"),
    dcc.Checklist(
        id="devices",
        options = all_df['Device'].value_counts().index,
        value = all_df['Device'].value_counts().index[1],
        inline=True
    ),
    html.Br(),
    dcc.Checklist(
        id="signals",
        options = ['V+', 'V-', 'I_tube', 'I_heat'],
        value = ['V+'],
        inline=True
    ),
])


@app.callback(
    Output("graph", "figure"), 
    Input("devices", "value"),
    Input("signals", "value"))
def update_line_chart(devices, signals):
    df = all_df # replace with your own data source
    mask = df.Device.isin(devices)
    fig = px.line(df[mask]
                  , x = "time"
                  , y = "I_heat"
                  , color = 'Device'
                  )
    
    return fig


app.run_server(
               # debug=True
              )
```

I also want to do the same with `device` (sub-setting the dataframe to certain categorical levels of `device`) but I guess this is quite similar(?).

Answer (score 1):

Currently in the plot code you write `y = all_df.columns == signals['value']`.

This returns an array with the same length as the number of columns containing a  boolean that indicates if the column name matches whatever is in `signal['value']`.
E.g. if your columns are `['time', 'V+', 'V-', 'I_tube', 'I_heat']` and `signals['value'] = 'V+'`, the result of `all_df.columns == signals['value']` is `array([False, True, False, False, False])`

However, the `y` parameter needs a (list of) column name(s). So you need to write `y=signals['value']` as that will pass the name of the selected column as a string.

For `device` the issue is the same, in the sense that you're not providing the arguments that `px.line` expects. To only provide dataframe rows with a certain `device` level write `df[df.Device == devices['value']]`.

Given the issues you encounter I would suggest to read the [plotly API reference](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/) and the [pandas manual on indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, this doesn't work. I receive " fig = px.line(df[df.Device == devices['value']]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str". It's the same for " y = signals['value'] ".

Comment: Oh I thought `devices` and `signals` were dicts? Apparently they are lists and you cannot index a list (e.g. `signals`) with a string (e.g. `value`), but you must index it using an integer (`0`, `1`, `2`, etc...) to get its elements. You need to figure out what type of object (list, string, dict, etc...) dash returns for a checklist.

Comment: Actually I followed https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/ so I don't see what I'm doing differently but I'll try to figure out, thank you!

Comment: What you're doing different from [that page, section on dash](https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/#line-charts-in-dash) is that you're trying to access a list by specifying a string. Nowhere in that example do they do that.

Comment: I updated it slightly. As far as I understand options within the devices-checklist is a list? At least when I execute this line in my IDE it returns as object a list. Ah, the "value" is a string..